# If Statement not being fulfilled, for some reason

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get a card to rotate 180 degrees when clicked, either turning it face up or face down.  I'm using Unity, C#.  Here is the code for the class attached to the card:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CardScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public float rotSpeed = 900;
    public MatchScript referenceEasy;

    private bool rotating = false;
    private bool faceUp = false;
    private bool finishedRotating = true;
    private int boardPosX, boardPosY;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        transform.localScale -= new Vector3(.6f, .6f, 0);
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 180f, 0f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Rotate();
    }

    void Rotate()
    {
        if (rotating && transform.eulerAngles.y >= 180 && !faceUp)
        {
            Debug.Log("ding");
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * (rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
        }
        else if (rotating && transform.eulerAngles.y <= 180 && faceUp)
        {
            Debug.Log("ding");
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * (rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
        }
        else if (rotating)
        {
            faceUp = !faceUp;
            rotating = false;
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        referenceEasy.Clicked(boardPosX, boardPosY);
        if(!rotating)
        {
            rotating = true;
            faceUp = !faceUp;
            Debug.Log(rotating);
            Debug.Log(eulerAngles.y);
            Debug.Log(faceUp);
        }

    }

    public void SetReference(MatchScript m) //When a card object is instantiated by the board, it will call this function, which associates the reference
    {
        referenceEasy = m;
    }

    public void SetBoardPosition (int x, int y) //This gets called to set where in the matrix the card exists.  It's mainly as a reference for the board.  
    {
        boardPosX = x;
        boardPosY = y;
    }
}
```

When clicked, the debug log tells me that faceUp and rotating are both true, and that the eulerAngles (in this case, the rotation) = 180.  However, neither 'ding' in the Rotate() is triggering, but I think I satisfy the requirements.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Place all three into 3 variables and check each on individually

Comment: Rotate is being called right? as in the update function is being called. you set a break point there and you know it's getting that far. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be better off putting those debug statements into the actual `Rotate` method so you can see what they are just before you use them.

In addition, be careful of floating point values (as your angles seem to be). It may *look* like it's 180 but it may *actually* be something like `179.99999942` or `180.00000007`.

The *other* thing you may want to look at is the different names you're using for the angles, specifically you're using `transform.eulerAngles.y` in one place and `eulerAngles.y` in another. It's not obvious from the code given that these refer to the same entity.

Comment: This was the issue, it was sliiiiiigtly off and only read as 180 degrees.  When I flipped the 'faceUp' variable, it managed to rotate.  The 'transform' that wasn't on that one eulerAngles was just a typo since I added it in post, not in code (I was throwing debugs everywhere).